# Siebel Open UI - View Applet not able to extend Applet PR

Tags: javascript, typescript, extend, siebel

We are facing issues while trying to extend existing vanilla TileLayout Applet PR to a custom View PR. We have tried multiple ways suggested by oracle to extend an Applet PR to another Applet PR but unable to find any reference where we need a view PR to extend Applet PR.
Requirement:
Our requirement is to display data in form of Tiles and apply custom PR logic on display of data. However on every NextSetofRecords our custom View PR doesn't get downloaded but the Vanilla Applet PR file still works. So all the events stop working which were added on View PR.
Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Tried SiebelJS.Extend to extend View PR the same way applet PR's are extended